# Why doesn't my api call return the proper data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, axios

```
import axios from 'axios';
import DashBooks from './BooksDisplay/dashBooks';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function CurrentlyReading() {
  const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/lists/get-list';
  const [list, setList] = useState({});
  const userId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  const name = 'Currently Reading';

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCurrent = async (userId, name) => {
      const listReq = { userId, name };
      console.log(listReq);
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(API_URL, listReq);
        if (response.data) {
          setList(response.data);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    getCurrent(userId._id, name);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="currentGrid">
      {list.books && list.books.map((b) => <DashBooks key={b._id} book={b} />)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default CurrentlyReading;
```

CurrentlyReading is a component that fetches a user list from my mongoDB database. The list has a list name property and a books array. I want to map over the books array and return a DashBooks component which displays the books in a card. I get the proper result on postman but not on the client.

Comment: This is probably a CORS issue. What is the error that you get in the browser console? What is the backend running?